# Hash Tables - Java

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, hashtable

Am about to do a homework, and i need to store quite a lot of information (Dictionary) in a data structure of my choice. I heard people in my classroom saying hash-tables are the way to go. How come?

Comment: It depends.  What are you trying to store?

Comment: Please provide more information, various data structure are good for various use, depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advantages**

When you first hear about hash tables they sound too good to be true. The reason is that is does not matter how many items there are searching, insertion (deletion sometimes) can take approximately 0(1) which is pretty much instantaneous from the user POV. Given its performance capabilities in terms of speed, hash tables are used mainly yet not limited to programs that need to look up thousands of items in less than a sec (for example spell-checkers / search engines). From my particular point of view I find H tables much easier to program than any sort of binary trees, and am not expert, so if you are a beginner that might too be an advantage.

**Disadvantages**

As hash tables are based on arrays they can be difficult to expand once created. Also I have read that for certain hash tables once full or getting full the speed when performing a task reduces notoriously. As a result of both when programming you will need to be fairly accurate of how many items you need to store. Additionally is not possible to search the items in the hash table in order for example from the smallest to the biggest, so if that is something you are looking for it might not be what you need.

---

**Extra Info**

Wikipedia article's - [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) - [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Tutorial on Hash Tables - [Tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=375)

All how to's about Hash Tables - [Java2S](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/0620__Hashtable-Basics.htm)

---

**Book Advice**

*I advice you to get a book called "Data Structures & Algorithms in Java - Second Edition - Robert Lafore" its a big book, but it has everything explained very subtle, for me is the only programming book so far i can read like is a novel.*

---

**Additional info regarding Big O notation - O(1)**

*O(1) doesn't mean "pretty much instantaneous" (an O(1) algorithm could take hours, weeks or years). It means (in this case) "is independent of the size of the collection" (assuming the hash code is good enough). – Ben Lings*

Thanks to Ben for his clarification.

---

P.S: You might want to be more descriptive in the future when you ask a question that way other users can pin-point what you are looking for.

Comment: O(1) doesn't mean "pretty much instantaneous" (an O(1) algorithm could take hours, weeks or years). It means (in this case) "is independent of the size of the collection" (assuming the hash code is good enough).

Comment: Thats correct, O(1) is constant time. What I meant was that for a user is pretty much instantaneous (Quoting from the book Data Structures & Algorithms in Java). Thanks for your clarification though.

Answer (score 3):

To help you out on deciding what type of collection is better for you, take a look at this Java Tutorials lesson:

[Lesson: Introduction to Collections](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html)

Reading this you can see which collection fits your needs.

Comment: @Spike Williams: No doubt. Maybe the best one to master the basics of the Java language.

Answer (score 3):

The best structure for your Dictionary would be a [Prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) in which each node's 'key' is a letter from one of your words and each node's 'value' is the meaning of the word (dictionary translation). Word lookup is linear on the word's length (the same as a hashtable, since your hash function would ideally be linear), or O(1) if we consider words as a whole. The thing that is better than hash tables is that a hash table will take a lot of space in order to ensure O(1) access and, depending on the words in the dictionary, it might be very sparsely populated. The prefix tree on the other hand actually provides compression - the tree itself will contain all the original information in less space than before, since common parts of words are shared along the tree structure. Dictionaries usually have tens of thousands words, leaving a prefix tree the only viable solution.

P.S. As mentioned earlier, the tree has almost infinite scalability, in contrast to a hash table.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to store and how you want to access it. You don't really provide enough information.

Hash tables provide O(1) lookup times so they can be used to retrieve values based on a key very quickly. If the hashing algorithm is expensive you may find that it is outperformed by other data structures. This is especially true if you are doing a lot of inserting and removing of items from the structure.

Comment: Technically the lookup time is O(n) not O(1) (because it's theoretically possible that every item in the hashmap has the same hash code as the item you're looking for), but in practice it's closer to O(1) (given a decent hashing function).

Comment: @sepp2k See "Introdution to Algorithms" page 259 for proof that in a hash table where collisions are resolved by chaining a search is an average of O(1)

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on using a hash table implementation from the Java libraries, be sure to note that there are two of them - HashTable, and HashMap. One of them is commonly used these days, and one is outdated and generally found in legacy code. Do some research to find out which is which, and why the newer one is better.

Answer (score 1):

A hashtable allows you to map keys to objects.

If you're storing values that have unique keys, and you will need to lookup the values by their keys, hashtables are the way to go.
If you just want to store an ordered set of objects without unique keys, an ordinary `ArrayList` is the way to go.  (In particular, note that ordinary hashtables are unordered)

Answer (score 1):

Hash Tables are good option but while using it you might have to decide what can be the good hash function.. this question can have many answers and depends on the programmer. I personally feel you can check out B+ tree or Trie. One of the main use of Trie is Dictionary representation.[Trie in Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Hope this helps !!